# How do I remove the sorting that comes when I use unstack in R?

Tags: r, list, ordereddictionary

I have created a list in R, along the lines of:

`alist <- as.list(unstack(DF, DF[,1]~DF[,2]))`

I am doing so using `unstack`, which I've learned applies sorting -- meaning the keys are sorted alphnumerically.

Unfortunately, later, I need to access the values by position in an lapply. I need to access them in the order they were inserted into the list.

Is there any way to remove the sorting from `unstack`?

Comment: You can access the elements of a `list` by key or index. What functionality does `OrderedDict` have that `list`s don't?

Comment: R doesn't order `list`s for you. How are you adding elements to it?

Comment: `unstack` is responsible for the sorting. Try something like `as.list(unstack(DF, DF[,1]~DF[,2])[unique(DF[,2])])`. `list`s are equivalent to Python's `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78945/discussion-between-matt-obrien-and-matthew-plourde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unstack` is responsible for the sorting. Try something like `as.list(unstack(DF, DF[,1]~DF[,2])[unique(DF[,2])])`. `list`s are equivalent to Python's `OrderedDict`.